# Invalid literal error message on palindrome checker/ works on vc code test but not leetcode

Tags: python

The program is meant to check to see if a number is a pallindrome.
the code I wrote changes the given int into a string, reverses it and then converts it back and checks to see if it matches the original number. I included a link to the error image
[leetcode][2]

```
class Solution:
def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:
    s = str(x)
    rev= s[::-1]
    newint=int(rev)
    if newint == x:
        return True
```

[image]

Comment: Please include the error message itself, not a link to it.

Comment: Well, is `121-` an integer?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You cannot convert the string `"121-"` to an int.

Comment: If the number is negative, you need to convert it to the corresponding positive number before checking if it's a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you probably need to add a check for a negative integer to your function.  Also, not knowing the full context of checking for a palindrome, you probably want to add in and else statement to return a value of False if the integer in question is not a palindrome.  With that, following is a snippet of code with a test loop to try out various integers.

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:
        if x < 0:
            x = x * -1
        s = str(x)
        rev= s[::-1]
        newint=int(rev)
        if newint == x:
            return True
        else:
            return False    # Otherwise, the function returns None
            
sl = Solution()

while True:
    z = int(input("Enter an integer or 0 to quit: "))
    if z == 0:
        break
    print(sl.isPalindrome(z))
```

Following are some test output at the terminal.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/Palindrome$ python3 Integer.py 
Enter an integer or 0 to quit: 121
True
Enter an integer or 0 to quit: -121
True
Enter an integer or 0 to quit: 1234
False
Enter an integer or 0 to quit: 432234
True
Enter an integer or 0 to quit: 0
@Una:~/Python_Programs/Palindrome$
```

Try that out and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: thanks no Dakker, apparently palindromes cannot be negatives so I just added a if x < 0 return false and the code passed the tests,